# Virtual Scrolling Issues in Kendo UI for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, virtualscroll

I am using Kendo UI Virtual Scrolling for my component which is in Angular. I have defined below properties in kendo grid.

The virtual scroll isnt working and displays all records on the page.

I dont find any good resources or documentation to fix this

Please let me know if more code is required.

```
        <kendo-grid
            #grid
            trackGridColumns
            [gridName]="gridName"
            [data]="gridView"
            [filterable]="true"
            [sortable]="true"
            [columnMenu]="true"
            [resizable]="true"
            scrollable="virtual"
            [rowHeight]="88"
            [filter]="state.filter"
            [skip]="0"
            [pageSize]="50"
            [sort]="state.sort"
            [height]="800"
            [pageable]="false"
            [selectable]="selectableSettings"
            [kendoGridSelectBy]="'id'"
            [(selectedKeys)]="dataSelection"
            (selectedKeysChange)="onSelectedKeysChange($event)"
            (dataStateChange)="onDataStateChange($event)"
            (sortChange)="handleSortChange($event)"
        >
```